# yq add extra contents to yaml

Tags: yaml, yq

I have tried many times with different combinations, but I cant get it working. Here is my yq command

`yq -i e '(.spec.template.spec.containers[]|select(.name == "od-fe").image) = "abcd"`

it is supposed to replace the deployment image which is successful, but it also adds  `template.spec.containers` to the service. here is the deployment + service yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: od
  name: od-fe
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: od-fe
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: od-fe
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: od-fe
          image: od-frontend:latest.  <<<replace here only
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: od
  name: od-fe-service
  labels:
    run: od-fe-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: od-fe
```

now the issue is service also get changed to become

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: od
  name: od-fe-service
  labels:
    run: od-fe-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: od-fe
  template:
    spec:
      containers: []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to fix that would be include a `select` statement at the top level to act on only `Deployment` type

```
yq e '(select(.kind == "Deployment").spec.template.spec.containers[]|select(.name == "od-fe").image) |= "abcd"' yaml
```

Note: If you are using yq version 4.18.1 or beyond, [the eval flag `e` is no longer needed](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1) as it has been made the default action.

Comment: great, it works!